# Outlook file format

Tags: pdf, outlook, msg, eml

When you drag a file form outlook inbox to say your desktop, it saves it as a MSG file, is it possible to change for file type? Ideally I would like pdf, but EML would also be exceptable.

It is so i can attached it to another PDF or phrase it in a php script.

Comment: By `drag&drop`, you will get a `.msg` file. Using the `file/save` menu, you can choose between several formats. Use `.html` and convert this to `.pdf` (with external tools) if desired. As an alternative, you could "print" the message into a `.pdf` file.

Comment: Thanks. I know these options, but i need this functionality when you drag and drop the file

Comment: This [GitHub project](https://github.com/tonyfederer/OutlookFileDrag) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is your responsibility to convert MSG file format to any other format. You can use the Outlook Object Model for that - `MailItem.SaveAs` exports to the txt, RTF, HTML, MHTML, and Doc formats.